# Delegate not executing after call swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, delegates, protocols

I have a viewController with another containerView insider set up to appear temporarily (added programmatically). The containerView is a sort of operation bar, which allows you to change values of the viewController. The protocol called from an IBAction of a button however, does not call the protocol set up inside the viewController class.

Here is the code from both classes:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, updateListDelegate {
    let dataSource = containerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource.delegate = self
    }

    func updateList(sender: containerView) {
        print("is called") //is not printed
    }
}
```

The code from the containerView:

```
protocol updateListDelegate {
    func updateList(containerView)
}

class containerView: UIViewController {
    var delegate: updateListDelegate?

    @IBAction func AddSong(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.updateList(sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `AddSong` being called?

Comment: Check whether AddSong is called or not.
@IBAction func AddSong(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("AddSong is called")
        delegate?.updateList()
    }

Comment: FYI - It is standard practice that class/struct/protocol/enum names start with uppercase letters. Function, variable, and case names start with lowercase letters. You have several of these backwards.

Comment: Yes, AddSong is being called (I have a separate code to it, which does run and the input marker indicating that the button is still connected to the IBAction is still filled)

Comment: Thank you, rmaddy. I was still a bit unsure with which ones to define with uppercase and which ones with lowercase.

Comment: You haven't connected your delegates, that is why it's not working. What exactly are you trying to do? The container view contains the view controller and from the view controller you want to execute a method in the container?

Comment: The viewController contains the containerView and from the containerView, I want to execute a method in the viewController. How would I then connect the delegates?

Comment: You are making a very common mistake. Please consider that the result of the default initializer `containerView()` is **not** the instance in the storyboard, it's a brand new instance without connected outlets and actions. You need the actual reference to the view controller. By the way: Please conform to the naming convention that class and protocol names start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this method is only to be called from one object, then, in my opinion, I would not define a protocol. If multiple objects are to call this method, then I would define a protocol. This is typically how you would call a method backwards, using a basic delegate.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = ContainerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        container.viewControllerDelegate = self
        // push to this instance of container at some point

    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("great success")
    }

}


class ContainerView: UIViewController {

    weak var viewControllerDelegate: ViewController?

    @objc func someAction() {
        if let viewControllerDelegate = viewControllerDelegate {
            viewControllerDelegate.doSomething()
        }
    }

}

// prints "great success" when someAction() called
```

One of the most common mistakes people make is not keeping track of instances. For delegates to work, you must be sure you are using the specific instances that you've instantiated and assigned those delegates to.